# NVMe SSD: Should fs block size be the physical reported sector or the logical one?

Tags: filesystems, nvme

So, I have an NVMe drive which reports the following:

```
NAME         ALIGNMENT MIN-IO OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED       RQ-SIZE   RA WSAME
nvme0n1              0 131072 131072   32768    4096    0 none           1023  256    0B
```

The NVMe ns is formatted with LBA=1 (4k) option (which is the second option after 512), but both `lsblk` and `parted` report sector size logical/physical as 4k/32k.

What block size should I use (is optimal) for the filesystem?